# Blackberry Push support in India

Tags: blackberry, push, blackberry-push

I have successfully pushed notifications to BB mobile phones based on the BB push SDK provided by RIM. I have currently tested this in Israel where our R&D is located.

Part of our team is in India, but for some reason they are not able to receive any notifications although they are using exactly the same client code, all credentials are entered correctly and the registration with RIM push server succeeds.

Any ideas? Does RIM not support India for pushes?

Comment: There was recently this big issue with the Indian government wanting access to all encrypted blackberry info, and RIM may have had to hack some changes to comply. Not sure if that would have anything to do with it, but its the best reason I can think of.

Comment: Hey can you please help me,I need help regarding Push API,wanted to implement Push API but not able to find any good quality resources,it would be great if u revert me back.

Answer (score 0):

I am based in Delhi and know a lot of people here who use Blackberry for their office email. Push email works just fine.